# Select from two tables PHP

Tags: php, sql

This should be a very simple code, but I can't figure it out. Basically I want to JOIN two tables. One of the tables has the name of the user and the other table has all the orders that 
that user submitted. I want a list of all the users, ORDERED by the user who has submitted the most orders. Is this possible using JOIN?

```
SELECT COUNT(table1.Orders)
        , table2.Name 
    FROM table1 
        LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.IDName = table1.IDName 
ORDER BY COUNT(table1.Orders)
```

This is the code I have right now. Thanks for taking a look at this, I look forward to hearing your responses.

Comment: You have a typo in the JOIN - `tabel1.IDName`

Comment: You should probably change `LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.IDName = table1.IDName` to `LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.IDName = table1.IDName` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use `GROUP BY` and sort by decreasing order. Your `JOIN` is wrong, I replaced `table1.IDName` with `table2.IDName`:

```
SELECT COUNT(table1.Orders) AS nb, table2.Name
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.IDName = table2.IDName
GROUP BY table.Name
ORDER BY nb DESC
```

Comment: +1 I saw you edited your answer with the proper join condition. =)

Answer (score 1):

My best guess from the top of my head would be that you try to join both tables on the same table and field, which doesn't make sense, if I understand correctly. How could you join results from two tables if you only use only field from a single table? Why write: `table1.IDName = table1.IDName`? I believe you shall write `table2.IDName = table1.IDName`.

Instead of:

```
SELECT COUNT(table1.Orders)
        , table2.Name 
    FROM table1 
        LEFT JOIN table2 ON tabel1.IDName = table1.IDName 
    ORDER BY COUNT(table1.Orders)
```

You shall write:

```
SELECT COUNT(table1.Orders)
        , table2.Name 
    FROM table1 
        LEFT JOIN table2 ON tabel2.IDName = table1.IDName 
    ORDER BY COUNT(table1.Orders)
```

Using the GROUP BY clause as suggested by **Jocelyn** is also a key point to verify.